# What is the difference between the gold and rainbow medals?

Tags: kirby-mass-attack

In *Kirby Mass Attack* most of the medals are gold, but some have a rainbow shimmer. What is the difference between the two types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.gamespot.com/ds/action/kirby-mass-attack/show_msgs.php?pid=609573&topic_id=m-1-60497889) on Gamespot:

> You have to collect the rainbow medal from each level to gain access to the final world of the game and beat the boss. If you miss any regular medals, you can get them later; but you must get the one rainbow medal from each level of the four main worlds, or you can't beat the game. If you missed any rainbow medals after beating the boss of World 4, you can then go back and get the ones you missed; so don't worry about having to get them all on your first try of each level.